# How can I add an image to UITabbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitabbar

I am trying to add an `image` to a `UITabbar`. Currently it's got a black color with the default shine. I want a solid color like below. How can I add this to `UITabbar` in a xib?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];
```

[Here is a better read on tabbar customization](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/)

Comment: Read that link also it will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

To customize a UITabBar, iOS 5 offers an API to let you change the background image of the tabbar.

```
// ios 5 code here

UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];

// ios 4 code here

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
UIView *tabbg_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIImage *tabbag_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PB_MD_footer_navBg_v2.png"];
UIColor *tabbg_color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:tabbag_image];
tabbg_view.backgroundColor = tabbg_color;
[tabBar insertSubview:tabbg_view atIndex:0];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
viewTab1controller = [[ViewTab1Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewTab1" bundle:nil];
viewTab1controller.title = @"Schedules";
navigationTab1Controller = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewTab1controller] autorelease];
navigationTab1Controller.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Match.png"] autorelease];
[viewTab1controller release];
```